# attach valums jquery ajax uploader to element

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

by default valums [ajax uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) uploaded creates a button for you. clicking the button opens "file explorer". once a file is selected it automatically uploads it for you. However I would like to have "`<input id="fileUpload" type="file" />`" and then a button underneath that would say "upload". Then clicking on the button would upload the file. I know it's doable but i can't figure it out. please help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery form plugin might work better for you. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload